# Swagger-PHP, no annotation with Symfony2 and NelmioApiDocBundle

Tags: rest, symfony, swagger

Is it possible to generate documentation for a RESTful API without annotations, but with, say a config file?

something like this:

```
[<route name>|MyBundle\Bundle\User]:
    "@ApiDoc(
        statusCodes={
        200="Returned when successful",
        403="Returned when the user is not authorized to say hello",
        404={
            "Returned when the user is not found",
            "Returned when something else is not found"
        }
     }
    )"
...
```

I need this because our current API inherits the CRUD behavior from the super class, instead of having a child method for each request.

So instead of having a bunch of ugly looking methods like this:

```
...

public function readAction()
{
    parent::readAction();
}
...
```

I'd rather do, if possible some patch to simulate the annotation behavior and auto-generate the annotation config file.

Has anyone done something similar?

Thank you.